# Is it possible to pagebreak a longtable if the next "n" amount of rows won't fit on page?

Tags: macros, page-breaking, longtable

I want to produce a `longtable` where some "elements" consist of multiple rows (see picture). I want the `longtable` to pagebreak if the next element doesn't fit in the table. Is there a way to tell `longtable` to do that for me?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand*\arraystretch{3}
\begin{longtable}{c c c c c}
some & serious & stuff\\
\hline
\endhead
& stuff \\
\\
\\
\\
 \\
\\
\\
 \\
\\
\\
\\
& is \\
& one \\
\textbf{\Large This} & of \\
& those \\
& elements \\
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/m0QscJl.png?1]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGFcg.png]

The desired behaviour **in this case** would be to pagebreak because the 5 rows don't fit on the page.

Comment: Have you tried `multirow`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an element consists of several rows, `\\*` can be used to prevent a page break between the rows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand*\arraystretch{3}
\begin{longtable}{c c c c c}
some & serious & stuff\\
\hline
\endhead
& stuff \\
\\
\\
\\
 \\
\\
\\
 \\
\\
\\
\\
& is \\
& one \\
\textbf{\Large This} & of \\*
& those \\*
& elements \\
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1]  [image: Page 2]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is good practice or not, but I manually put in a \pagebreak just before the rows that won't fit in order to make them go onto the next page before the auto-break longtable usually puts in.